# npm install error -> Windows_NT 6.1.7601

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install

I'm getting below error while installing any module using `npm install <module-name>`

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm" "-g"
npm ERR! node v5.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\npm-debug.log
```

I tried

- command prompt with Administrator access
- few older and latest versions of `NodeJS` and `npm`
- many Blogs/StackOverflow's accepted answers

Comment: Which are your node and npm versions? There can be bugs fixed in newer versions.

Comment: I tried latest versions for both

Comment: Could you post the whole error?

Comment: @məˈSHēn updated whole error.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: there is no proxy

Comment: can you `ping registry.npmjs.org`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the detail at the log file generated at the same folder you issued the command:

cat npm-debug.log
In my case the error was related a mistake made during typing the content of the package.json:

Comment: I'm trying to install globally :)